# How do I use an Operator like */+- and an string in a Dictionary python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a beginner and want to know, how it should work.It should be a calculator and the problem is, that when an operator are there as the input, it get a string. If I cant put an operator(not a string) next to an String in a dictionary, how should I do it, that it works with integers AND floats? Thanks

```
zahl1 = input('Bitte geben sie die erste Zahl an')
op = input('''
welcher Operator soll benutzt werden?
Hier, einige Möglichkeiten:
+, -, *(mal), /(geteilt), //(geteilt, ohne den Rest) ''')
zahl2 = int(input('Bitte geben sie die zweite Zahl an'))

operator = {'+':'+', '-':-, '/':'/', '//':'//', '*':'*'}

  
print('Das Ergebnis lautet: ',zahl1, operator[op], zahl2)
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Before we can give you any help, we need you to specify what you're trying to do, and what problem you have.

Comment: Your posted code has a syntax error, in that you didn't put quotes around one of your values.  Your logic has an error, in that your dict has no purpose: it maps characters to themselves.

Comment: All of the operators are available as functions, so you can map to those functions. See the function list at https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html.  For example, `{'+': operator.add, ...}` might be what you are looking for (with other changes to your code to properly adapt...)

Comment: There is a problem: Python do not get it as an operator, it get it as <function <native JS>> and there arent any calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

```
import operator
dictCalc = { "-": operator.sub, "/": operator.truediv,"+":operator.add,"*":operator.mul}
```

Comment: There is a problem: Python do not get it as an operator, it get it as <function <native JS>> and there arent any calculations